# Invalid UVs containing NaN values After Trying To Export FBX file (edit: Attached .blend file)

Tags: uv, export

every time I try to export via .fbx I get this error. [image]

[image]

What I was doing:
I have a project I'm working on that needs constant tweaking in the game engine, but this engine only accepts .fbx, so I can keep all the modifiers live and iterate if needed. This engine also requires that every mesh/object have a material assigned to it via the 3d software before export, and because I wasn't done working on the file I thought I would assign a temporary material called **!Pink** and assigned it to all the objects in the scene that didn't have a material assigned to them. Well, the engine did not accept the question mark in front of the word as a valid material name. So I decided I was going to finish up the project and assign proper names to each and every object. That left me with Orphan Data, so I purged those materials and tried to export again to .fbx, and now I am getting this error.

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx_*init*_.py", line 663, in execute
> return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3627, in save
> ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3510, in save_single
> fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3307, in fbx_objects_elements
> fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1397, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
> raise RuntimeError("UV layer %s on %r has invalid UVs containing NaN values" % (uvlayer.name, me))
> RuntimeError: UV layer UVMap on bpy.data.meshes['Mesh.052'] has invalid UVs containing NaN values

Also, every time I purge the Orphan Data and try to export these 50+ meshes they reappear in the list with different names "mesh.01, mesh.02" etc even though i didn't have any objects with that naming convention. These are the meshes I applied the same **!Pink** material to:
[image]

[image]

And this is my objects list none of these objects have the name 'mesh' in them, they are all numbers:
[image: And this is my objects list:]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  This can help to narrow it down to the blend file or FBX plugin issue.

Comment: I would use _File_ > _Clean Up_ > _Recursive Unused Data-Blocks_ (the "recursive" part is important). For the "mesh" names: the objects have numbers as names, but those are not the mesh data names. For example, the default cube is called "Cube", the mesh data is "Cube" as well. Simply duplicate the cube with `Ctrl`+`D`, the new object is named "Cube.001" (because no two objects can have the same name) as well as the mesh data. But a linked duplicate with `Alt`+`D` will have the object name "Cube.001", but the mesh data is still "Cube" (with 2 behind the name field) because two objects use it.

Comment: For the export error with the _"invalid UVs containing NaN values"_ there are a lot of possibilities mentioned in these bug reports: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/102783 and https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/79775 for example, somehow your UVs might be messed up (I'm not gonna list all ways that could have happened which are mentioned there), in most cases the way to repair them seems to be deleting the UV map and creating it new. All in all this seems to be an issue where Blender creates these invalid values when there is something wrong with the mesh.